# Injecting AutoMapper dependencies using Ninject

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, ninject, automapper, bootstrapping

I am having trouble injecting AutoMapper into an ASP.NET MVC 2 application using Ninject. I used Jimmy Bogard's post on [AutoMapper and StructureMap type Configuration](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/05/11/automapper-and-ioc.aspx) as a guide.

```
public class AutoMapperModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<ITypeMapFactory>().To<TypeMapFactory>();
        Bind<Configuration>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope().WithConstructorArgument("mapper", MapperRegistry.AllMappers);
        Bind<IConfiguration>().To<Configuration>();
        Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().To<Configuration>();
        Bind<IMappingEngine>().To<MappingEngine>();
    }
}
```

Ninject throws an exception when resolving `Configuration`.

> Error activating IObjectMapper 
>   No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>   3) Injection of dependency IObjectMapper into parameter mappers of constructor of type Configuration

**Update**

This is now working using the following binding:

```
    Bind<ITypeMapFactory>().To<TypeMapFactory>();
    Bind<Configuration>().ToConstant(new Configuration(Kernel.Get<ITypeMapFactory>(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers())).InSingletonScope();
    Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<Configuration>());
    Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<Configuration>());
    Bind<IMappingEngine>().To<MappingEngine>();
```

I published the module on GitHub. [AutoMapper.Ninject](http://github.com/coreycoto/AutoMapper.Ninject). More information on my blog: http://binaryspeakeasy.com/2010/09/automapper-ninject/

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/1810728/11635

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working but it doesn't feel very clean creating an instance of the Configuration class. Any suggestions to clean it up further.

```
        Bind<ITypeMapFactory>().To<TypeMapFactory>();
        Bind<Configuration>().ToConstant(new Configuration(Kernel.Get<ITypeMapFactory>(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers())).InSingletonScope();
        Bind<IConfiguration>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<Configuration>());
        Bind<IConfigurationProvider>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<Configuration>());
        Bind<IMappingEngine>().To<MappingEngine>();
```

Comment: best to edit this into your question. In general I'd say you're overusing `Bind<IX>().ToMethod(c => c.Kernel.Get<X>()`. Just use `Bind<IX>().To<X>()`

Comment: Ditto `Bind<Configuration>().ToConstant(new Configuration(Kernel.Get<ITypeMapFactory>(), MapperRegistry.AllMappers())).InSingletonScope();` should map to `.To<>.WithConstructorArgument`....

Answer (score 11):

You can do this is a one liner using the latest version (currently 2.2.0).

```
kernel.Rebind<IMappingEngine>().ToMethod(context => Mapper.Engine);
```

As an extra, I do agree with fodonnel, adding a facade to hide the Automapper interface is a good idea, however I wouldn't take the signatures directly from Automapper, unless you need all that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

It might also be a good idea to introduce a mapping facade. Instead of passing IMappingEngine through out your code create an IObjectMapper interface. The interface I use contains method signatures taken directly out of automappers code.

```
public interface IObjectMapper
{ 
  TDestination Map(TSource source);
  TDestination Map(TSource source, TDestination destination);
  object Map(object source, Type sourceType, Type destinationType);
  object Map(object source, object destination, Type sourceType, Type destinationType);
}
```

Your configuration is still going to be automapper dependent.

A blog post I wrote on it is here: http://fodonnel.wordpress.com/2010/09/20/an-object-mapper-facade/

Comment: The blog link is dead.